# Wavesurfer timeline plugin download is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, wavesurfer.js

I want to add timeline for digital audio file using wavesurfer.js unfortunately my code here does not work. May I know from where can I load the timeline.js for my file? Is wavesurfer timeline plugin deprecated?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>webapp</title>


    <!-- main wavesurfer.js lib -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>

    <!-- wavesurfer.js timeline -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/plugin/wavesurfer.timeline.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sidebar.css" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
<div id="waveform-timeline"></div>    
            <div id="audio-spectrum"></div>
 </body>
    </html>
```

javascript:

```
var Spectrum = WaveSurfer.create({
                    container: '#audio-spectrum',
                    progressColor: "#03a9f4",
                    container: document.querySelector('#audio-spectrum'),
                    backend: 'MediaElement'
                });

Spectrum.on('ready', function () {
                   var timeline = Object.create(Spectrum.Timeline);

                       timeline.init({
                       Spectrum: Spectrum,
                       container: "#wave-timeline"
                       });
                     });

                // Load the audio file from your domain !
                Spectrum.load('http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');
```

error says wavesurfer is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The timeline plugins requires you to pass the wavesurfer instance to its `create` function. You are passing it under the key `Spectrum` – that's why it can't be found. Change your timeline initialisation code to:

```
// ...
timeline.init({
  wavesurfer: Spectrum,
  container: "#wave-timeline"
});
// ...
```

Comment: sure i will try this.

Comment: no luck . I tried creating wavesurfer object instead of Spectrum. still timeline can not load.

Comment: wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
               var timeline = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Timeline);

               timeline.init({
               wavesurfer: wavesurfer,
               container: '#waveform-timeline'
                  });
               }); this code did work!!